# Adding "Relevant Courses" Section with proper formatting to Jake's Resume Template

Tags: macros, spacing, formatting, overleaf, resume

I am a beginner in Latex, and am trying to create a resume using the "Jake's Resume" template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume/syzfjbzwjncs). I am currently trying to add a "Relevant Coursework section" in the education section, which lists the courses I take that are of my major.

I tried modifying this command

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
```

and made my own new command to look something like

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingNew}[5]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
    \\
    \vspace{2pt}\item{#5}
    
}
```

Now I am able to add the relevant coursework, but the formatting is inconsistent with the other elements.
The section looks something like this:

[image]

How do I make this section consistent with the other ones?